# Why javascript is not well constructing my date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular 6 project, I have the following code:

```
const date1 = new Date(2018, 9, 17);
console.log('date1 = ', date1);
```

But I get the following result in the cosole of my browser:

```
date1 =  Wed Oct 17 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

Why do I get Oct but not Sept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because

> The argument monthIndex is 0-based. This means that January = 0 and December = 11.

For More: [Date Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)